# Leafletjs split polygon

Tags: leaflet, turf, spatial-analysis

I have a polygon and it has circles on it. I drew lines from the intersections of the circles. Actually I want to split this big polygon by lines. I have numbered the polygons to be divided in the figure.

I have uploaded all the code both in the jsfiddle environment and here.

I have a polygon in my codes and there are two circles on it. I created lines from the intersections of the circles. I want to split the polygon according to these lines as shown in the figure

JsFiddle Link:      https://jsfiddle.net/hrnbydgn/et2635hq/2

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([41.2819587,28.4810230], 18);

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);


var cor3 = [
        [41.2819587,28.4810230],
        [41.2831258,28.4795746],
        [41.2834906,28.4823748],
        [41.2820716,28.4816051],
        [41.2819587,28.4810230]
    ];

var p3 = L.polyline(cor3, {
  polygon: true,
  fill: true,
  color:'yellow'
});
var ObsCenter = new Array();
var bboxObs = new Array();
var center = [28.480423339203874,41.28301959608716];
ObsCenter.push(center);
var radius = 6;
var options = {steps: 10, units: 'meters'};
var circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);
var t1 = L.geoJSON(circle).addTo(map); 
let bbox = turf.bbox(circle);
bboxObs.push(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox));

var center = [28.480823339215884,41.28261979629536];
ObsCenter.push(center);
var radius = 7;
var options = {steps: 10, units: 'meters'};
var circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);
var t1 = L.geoJSON(circle).addTo(map); 

bbox = turf.bbox(circle);
bboxObs.push(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox));

var polygon = turf.lineToPolygon(p3.toGeoJSON());
L.geoJSON(polygon).addTo(map);

let bbox2 = turf.bbox(polygon);
let bboxPoly = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox2);

var splice = new Array();

for(var sp = 0; sp<bboxObs.length; sp++){
splice.push([
[bboxPoly["bbox"][1],bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][0]],
[bboxPoly["bbox"][3],bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][0]]
]);

splice.push([
[bboxPoly["bbox"][1],bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][2]],
[bboxPoly["bbox"][3],bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][2]]
]);


splice.push([
[bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][1],bboxPoly["bbox"][0]],
[bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][1],bboxPoly["bbox"][2]]
]);

splice.push([
[bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][3],bboxPoly["bbox"][0]],
[bboxObs[sp]["bbox"][3],bboxPoly["bbox"][2]]
]);

}

var spliced = new L.Polyline(splice, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script><script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6.5.0/turf.min.js'></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 1908px; height: 1080px;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to split the polygon or just cut out square around circled number?

Comment: yes, just split polygon. this answer not solved @TomazicM

Comment: How does then the final polygon collection looks like? Do you then get 25 polygons in the above image?

Comment: Since there's no response I assume you are not interested in answer any more.